# ASP.NET MVC/JavaScript Add form element with JS & link element to model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make a page where you'd press a button, 'Add Option', and it'd add another `<input asp-for>` to the form during runtime, which would then append the newly added `<input asp-for>`'s value to the Model's `IEnumerable<PollOption>`.

What's the best way to do it with JavaScript, if it's possible?

Here's what I have:

`index.cshtml`

```cs
<form method="post">
    <div id="optionsContainer" class="col-8 pt-4">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-6 text-center text-light">
                Poll Title
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="PollTitle" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group row">
            <button id="addNewOptionBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Option</button>
            <div class="col-6 text-center text-light">
                Options:
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">Create Poll</button>
</form>
```

`PollModel`

```cs
[BsonId]
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
public int PollId { get; set; }
public string? PollTitle { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<PollOptionModel>? PollOptions { get; set; }
public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

`PollOptionModel`

```cs
[BsonId]
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
public int OptionId { get; set; }
public string? Option { get; set; }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a div with class name `option-container`.

```
<form method="post">
    ...
    <div class="form-group row">
       <button id="addNewOptionBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Option</button>
       <div class="col-6 text-center text-light">
          Options:
          <div class="option-container">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Then add this script (jquery is included by default in .net mvc), this will add a click event to your button which will add input fields.

```
@section scripts {
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

         // click event
         $("#addNewOptionBtn").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            // this will be used as the index of the Ienumerable
            var count = $(".options").length;

            // new input fields to be inserted
            var newOption = "<input name='PollOptions["+count+"].OptionId' placeholder='Option ID' value='"+count+"' /><input name='PollOptions["+count+"].Option' placeholder='Option' /><br/><br/>";

            // insert the new input fields
            $(newOption).appendTo(".option-container");
         })
      });
   </script>
}
```

Hit submit in your form, add a break point on your code and check to see if the new poll options are bound to the model.

Comment: Yes, it does bind it to PollOptionsModel in the Model. Thank you for this. Is there way that I can have the OptionId automatically be put in? Like: `"...value='PollOptions["+count+"].OptionId'..."`

Comment: yes, you can add a `value` attribute. `<input ... value='"+count+"'>`.
I updated the answer. You can mark this as the correct answer if it helped. Thanks!

Comment: i've ran into an issue. it doesn't seem to add other options in the DB, only the first one. is there also a way to define the id? i think its because the `_id` in the DB is the same when i insert.

Comment: @agisaeafafas will you make a new question and include a screenshot while debugging on how many items are in the ienumerable polloptions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193523/asp-net-mvc-javascript-only-1-of-added-inputs-is-inserted-into-db